# Homebrew: how to list the N last installed packages?

Tags: macos, homebrew, jq

Simply put: I want to list the last N packages I've installed with Homebrew.

What is the best (and possibly fastest) way to accomplish this?

Note that I'm not fluent in Ruby, so any suggestions to 'hack the Homebrew code to do what you want' would get me nervous...

##### What I tried so far

1. Read man pages, documentation, the Homebrew website, StackOverflow, googled with all sorts of variant questions, etc. No luck so far.
2. `brew info [formula|cask]` will actually tell the date when a formula/cask has been *poured* (which I assume means 'installed' outside the Homebrewosphere). So that value must be written somewhere — a database? a log?
3. Maybe there is an option to extract the poured date information via the [JSON API](https://docs.brew.sh/Querying-Brew.html)? But the truth is that with Homebrew 3.1.9-121-g654c78c, I couldn't get any `poured-date` or similar element on the JSON output... the only dates that I get are related to `git` (presumably because they're more useful for Homebrew's internal workings). This would, in theory, be able to tell me what are the 'newest' versions of the formulae I have installed, but *not* the *order* I have installed them — in other words, I could have installed a year-old version yesterday, and I don't need to know that it's one year old, I only want to know I've installed it yesterday!

##### What I *learned* so far

Although I couldn't figure out how to retrieve that information, I'm sure it *is* there, since `brew info ...` *will* give the *correct* day a particular formula was poured. Thus, one possible solution would be to capture *all* the information from `brew info` and then do a `grep` on it; thus, something like `brew info | grep Poured` should give me what I want. Needless to say, this takes *eternities* to run (in fact, I never managed to complete it — I gave up after several minutes).

Of course, I found out that there *is* a `brew info --installed` option — but currently, it only works with JSON output. And since JSON output will *not* tell the poured date, this isn't useful.

A possibility would be to do it in the following way:

- Extract all installed package names with `brew info --installed --json=v1 | jq "map(.name)" > inst.json`
- Parse the result so that it becomes a single line, e.g. `cat inst.json | tr -d '\n\r\[\]\"\,'`
- Now run `brew info --formula` (treat everything as a formula to avoid warnings) with that single line, pipe the result in another file (e.g. `all-installed.txt`)
- Go through that file, extract the line with the formula name and the date, and format it using something like `cat all-installed.txt | sed -E 's/([[:alnum:]]+):? stable.*\n(.*\n){3,7}^  Poured from bottle on (.*)$/\1 -- \3\\n/g' | sort | tail -40` — the idea is to have lines just with the date and the formula name, so that it can get easily sorted *[note: I'm aware that the regex shown doesn't work, it was just part of a failed attempt before I gave up this approach]*

Messy. It also takes a lot of time to process everything. You *can* put it all in a single line and avoid the intermediary files, if you're prepared to stare at a blank screen and wait for several minutes.

##### The quick and dirty approach

I was trying to look for *a)* installation logs; *b)* some sort of database where `brew` would store the information I was trying to extract (and that `brew info` has access to). Most of the 'logs' I found were actually related to patching individual packages (so that if something goes wrong, you can presumably email the maintainer). However, by sheer chance, I *also* noticed that every package has an `INSTALL_RECEIPT.json` inside `/usr/local/Cellar/`, which *seems* to have the output of `brew info --json=v1 package-name`. Whatever the purpose of this file, it has a precious bit of information: it has been created on the date that this package was installed!

That was quite a bit of luck for me, because *now* I could simply `stat` this file and get its creation timestamp. Because the formula directories are quite well-formed and easy to parse, I could do something very simple, just using `stat` and some formatting things which took me an eternity to figure out (mostly because `stat` under BSD-inspired Unixes has different options than those popular with the SysV-inspired Linux).

For example, to get the last 40 installed formulae:

```sh
stat -t '%Y%m%d%H%M' -f "%Sc %N %@" /usr/local/Cellar/*/*/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json | sort | tail -40
```

This runs reasonably fast, and I certainly managed to get exactly what I wanted/needed for another project (list the last few formulae that I had to install in order to run a certain software package that I'm attempting to get to compile under macOS and document what is needed), but I kept wondering if this is the 'best' approach. Sure, it's fast enough — it's way faster to traverse a filesystem tree using standard tools than expecting Ruby to do its slow-paced work — but how do I know that I have the 'correct' information? Do *all* packages have an `INSTALL_RECEIPT.json`? What if the Homebrew core developers think of completely changing the whole directory structure? Or stop writing that `INSTALL_RECEIPT.json` file because they use a database 'elsewhere' (where?) and this became redundant? In other words — how can I figure out what I want in a future-proof way, relying only on whatever information that the `brew` command already supplies?

Anyway, for the sake of the argument, I'd be quite welcome to see some suggestions on how to do this *correctly* — and without 'cheating' as I did with `stat` (e.g. not going through the `brew` command at all but rather relying on the filesystem itself).

Or maybe such functionality does not exist and I should put a feature request on Homebrew's GitHub issues? (After all, Debian/Ubuntu Linux users *have* a way to [get that information](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17012/is-it-possible-to-get-a-list-of-most-recently-installed-packages) using some parameters for `apt` and a bit of parsing... we 'deserve' the same, or even better! )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The "brew list" command has a -t option:

> Sort formulae and/or casks by time                                    modified, listing most recently modified                                  first.

Thus to get the most recent 40, you could write:

```
brew list -1t 2> /dev/null | head -n 40
```

There's also a -l option, which shows the timestamps that are used.

Running `brew list -t -v` shows what's happening under the hood; on my machine, the output begins:

```
==> Formulae
ls -t /usr/local/Cellar
```

So it's clear that `brew list` is (currently) relying on the "Cellar".

If `brew list` is too slow for your liking, I believe it would be reasonable to use HOMEBREW_PREFIX (as revealed by `brew --prefix`) in combination with either `Cellar` or `Cellar/*/*/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json`

### .time

The JSON object in each INSTALL_RECEIPT.json has a .time key, which would presumably be more reliable than a file or directory time stamp, so you might like to consider something like this bash script:

```
CELLAR=$(brew --prefix)/Cellar
jq -nr --arg cellar "$CELLAR" '
  [inputs | {time, file: (input_filename|sub($cellar;"") | sub("/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json";""))}]
  | sort_by(.time)[-40:][]
  | .file
' $CELLAR/*/*/INSTALL_RECEIPT.json
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! :-) Somehow, I missed the `-t` flag when doing a `brew help list`. But it surely is there! And it does pretty much what I needed, _and_ is quick enough for my purposes. Your second solution is a bit more intricate, but it has the merit of explaining what the `.time` parameter means in `INSTALL_RECEIPT.json`. I've checked, and it's indeed the 'correct' time!

Comment: By the way, the JSON elicited by `brew info --json installed` presumably ought to have the time, so it would make sense to propose an enhancement.